# Having trouble with my table sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filtering

I'm close to my desired output of being able to sort my table according to each header but it seems there are a few errors with my JS. I can't seem to figure out why it's not quite sorting by each header and also I cannot seem to figure out how to have my scripts distinguish weather the `<td>` value is an input for just plain text. I need to be able to filter by ALL these `<th>`s weather the `<td>`s have an input for not.
Here is my fiddle and the main function is below
https://jsfiddle.net/eut7qxf6/2/

```
    var table = $('#user-table');

$('#sort-username, #sort-phone, #sort-firstname, #sort-id')
    .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
    .each(function(){

        var th = $(this),
            thIndex = th.index(),
            inverse = false;

        th.click(function(){

            table.find('td input').filter(function(){

                return $(this).index() === thIndex;

            }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                return $(a).attr('value') > $(b).attr('value') ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1
                    : inverse ? 1 : -1;

            }, function(){

                // parentNode is the element we want to move
                return this.parentNode.parentNode; 

            });

            inverse = !inverse;

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

First, you are trying to use index function on the object returned by:

```
table.find('td input')
```

This is always returning 0, since $(this) variable points to an input that is the first child of its cell (td). So the solution would be replace your table.find with:

```
table.find('td')
```

Now we are able to verify if $(this).index() matches with the index of the th that was clicked.

Of course, this change make other changes required in your code. First of them is that your sortElement function now needs a find of it's own in order to get the input value:

```
return $(a).find('input').attr('value') > $(b).find('input').attr('value') ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1
                    : inverse ? 1 : -1;
```

And the last function, refered as getSortable on sortElements plugin, would need a change as well:

```
return this.parentNode;
```

Second, you need to take in consideration if there is a input in the cells of the selected column, if there is no input, then you have to consider the value that is directly inside the cell itself.

Like this:

```
var inputA = $(a).find('input').attr('value');
var inputB = $(b).find('input').attr('value');

var valueA = null;
var valueB = null;

if (inputA == null) {
    valueA = parseInt($(a).html());
    valueB = parseInt($(b).html());
} else {
    valueA = $(a).find('input').val();
    valueB = $(b).find('input').val();
}
```

So, to make it clear i have forked your jsfiddle [in the version that I have made all the changes](https://jsfiddle.net/c91qk1La/).

Comment: Working a lot better, thank you! But unfortunately looks the id's get jumbled when  you try and sort by id =/

Comment: I have update the example on JSFiddle to make it work with all columns